# Multiple events happening after KeyEvent.VK_SPACE occured

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, keyevent

Not sure why. My method runs multiple times and prints string "Fire !!!" 
It should only run, once after event occurred.

Player class

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{
        Missilies m = new Missilies(x,y);
        //m.fire();
        if(!m.isFired()) {
            m.fire();
            m.setFired(true); 
        }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{
        m.setFired(false);
    }
```

Missile class

```
public  void fire(){
    System.out.println("Fire !!!");

 }
```

now this seems to work:

```
 @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{
        Missilies m = new Missilies(x,y);
        if (lastKey == null || lastKey != e.getKeyChar()) {
            lastKey = e.getKeyChar();
            m.fire();
            System.out.println("keyPressed: " + lastKey);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a KeyEvent in Java only happen once even when key is held](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642854/make-a-keyevent-in-java-only-happen-once-even-when-key-is-held)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No specs, no teachers. Just me. Working on small video game and want it to be available online from the webpage. Plus mastering my JAVA skills.

Comment: In that case, code a `JFrame` and launch it direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html):

`keyPressed()` will keep firing so long as the key is held down.  You *could* put the code into `keyReleased()` but then it'd probably feel weird to the player if the missile was firing when they let go of the key.  Better would be to put some kind of check in place to make sure it only fires once for each event.

```
boolean fired;

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{
        m = new Missilies(x,y);
        if(!fired) {
            m.fire();
            fired = true;
        }
        break;
}

@Override
public void keyRelased(KeyEvent e) {
    fired = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you set a boolean 'fired' field and create a setter for it?  (Edited to show that. Sorry, I probably should have shown that in the first place.)

Comment: private boolean fired;
 
 public boolean isFired() {
  return fired;
 }
 public void setFired(boolean fired) {
  this.fired = fired;
 }

Comment: My bad.  I misread your original code.  How about my new edit?

Comment: Still does it. Still fires like 100 times. Could be the timer issue?